# How to make a section uneditable in jhtmlarea editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, jhtmlarea

I'm using [jhtmlarea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/) to let the users to edit a pre-selected template in the browser itself. Here's the below (compact) markup for that.

```
<textarea name="textBoxEditor" rows="2" cols="20" id="textBoxEditor">
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</textarea>
```

What I need is that not allow the user to edit 'header' even though it's inside the textarea. Is there a way to do it? I tried giving it a 'readonly' and 'disabled' attributes even tried to set an overlay div on top of it with higher z-index but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to make just a section of the content within the jHtmlArea editable. If you want to have a static header and footer while allowing the users to only edit the body content, then you should setup the jHtmlArea to only edit the editable content.